# How get the javascript class that created a jQuery element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding Tiles to my Tilegame by using a javascript equivalent of class instances, like this:

```
for(var i = ... ) {
    var myTile = new Tile();
}
```

This Tile instance adds a div element to the DOM.
Inside the Tile class it looks something like this:

```
function Tile(){
    this.init = function(){
         $( "game" ).append( "<div class='graph'>yo</div>" );
    }
    this.doSomething = function(){
       // I want to call this function from a generic single click listener for the entire game
    }
}
```

Then, the whole game has one single listener that checks if the entire game container is clicked. Using event.target I can then check which div was clicked.

```
function containerWasClicked(evt){
   console.log("somebody clicked on " + evt.target);
   // BUT I cannot call evt.target.doSomething(); because the div does not know who created it...
}
```

Now I know which div was clicked, but how do I find the Tile instance that appended the div to the dom? I don't want to add a listener to every single element individually.

Comment: Just to clarify, there's no such thing as a "jQuery element" or a "jQuery div".

Comment: Actual Tile class? You mean the object instance from Tile that reference a specific DOM element?

Comment: would it be acceptable to include the information (which class the "Title" element had when the graph was created) in a dataset property of the graph elements?

Comment: try looking into data-binding tool like Knockoutjs. This does this all out of the box

Comment: Knockout looks interesting, but perhaps not particularly suited to games. But if it can treat JS objects as visual elements automatically, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of an anti-pattern really; but jQuery allows you to set data on an element; you could use it as follows:

```
function Tile(){
    this.init = function(){
        var $el = $("<div class='graph'>yo</div>");
        $el.data("creator", this);
        $( "game" ).append( $el );
    }
    this.doSomething = function(){
       // I want to call this function from a generic single click listener for the entire game
    }
}
```

And then later on to retrieve it:

```
var instance = $(evt.target).data("creator");
instance.doSomething();
```

Comment: is it wise/does it work to store a reference in the html, instead of just an ID and store the tiles data/classes in an array

Comment: @RenePot it's certainly not harmful; however it doesn't look particularly nice. In an ideal world each Tile class would bind it's own element's click handler and deal with it internally.

Comment: In my case I like having a single click listener that can handle whatever element you happen to have clicked. It removes the need to add and remove listeners continuously and it also works for any other element in the game - not just the tiles. I agree having a reference inside the jQuery element seems kind of ugly...

Answer (score 5):

Rather than doing the delegation work yourself, just use jQuery's built-in ability to do it.

First, when you create your elements, save a reference to your Tile object as data:

```
this.init = function(){
     var graph = $("<div/>", {
       text: "yo",
       "class": "graph",
       data: { "tile": this }
     });
     $( "#game" ).append( graph );
};
```

Now you can set up your event handler:

```
$("#game").on("click", ".graph", function() {
  var theGraph = this;
  var tile = $(theGraph).data("tile");
  // ...
  tile.doSomething();
});
```

By initializing the jQuery "data" map to have a reference to the Tile instance, you make the object available later.

Answer (score 0):

Using "this" will refer to the element that is clicked.

```
$('.graph').on("click", function(){
 $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Yes, but the question is how to get the Tile instance that created the div element, so that I can call "doSomething()" on it.

Answer (score 0):

All your tiles have a class `graph`. If you add a listener to that class, then you can access your tile by using `$(this)` in your callback, like so;

```
$(function(){
    $(".graph").click(function(){ $(this).remove() });
});
```

Comment: In this case, $(this) still only refers to the div element. I cannot call $(this).doSomething();